# Grails access value from belongsTo in domain?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm, relationship

I am working on a Grails project and I have a User domain model with the following:

```
class SecUser {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String email
    String password
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    static belongsTo = [area:Areas] 

    .....
}
```

I am also using the springSecurityUI and I have this on the create user view:

```
<s2ui:textFieldRow readonly='yes' name='area' labelCode='user.area.label' bean="${user}"
                                labelCodeDefault='Area' value="${area}"/>
```

When I see the create view instead of seeing the box for area populate with the area of the current logged in user I can see the following:

```
com.testapp.Areas : 1
```

I am presuming this is the id of the Dept for this user but I want to show the actual value, how can I do this for relational objects?

Thanks for the help

EDIT.......

Below is my Areas class as it stands

class Areas {

```
String name

static hasMany = [users:SecUser]
```

}

EDIT...

I have now fixed this using:

```
value="${area.name}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display the actual **id** attribute, then you can do so like this:

```
<s2ui:textFieldRow readonly='yes' name='area' labelCode='user.area.label' bean="${user}"
                            labelCodeDefault='Area' value="${area?.id}"/>
```

Comment: The create user page has a read-only field called "area" which i want to equal the value of the current logged in user trying to create a user, so this code would not work unfortunately, any other ideas?

Comment: i don't have enough privileges to comment all around yet, but in response to your latest comment - just set the accessor to **name** instead of **id** if that's what you want displayed! **value="${area?.name}"**

Answer (score 1):

`com.testapp.Areas : 1` is the output of the default `toString()` method. To change the output, you need to write your own `toString()` on `Areas`.

```
class Areas {

    String toString() {
        "the actual string representation of my Areas object"
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't know how to write a toString()?

Comment: Yes I just don't understand how this fits into the problem I am having. I have updated my post with my Area Class as it stands, how would I modify this so that I can pull the Area value back for that user? Thanks for the help

Comment: What do you mean "the Area value"

Comment: When the application first starts I have bootstrapped some test data into it, this data creates a user say "admin" and then as you can see from the SecUser class this user should belong to an area so I set that as belonging to say "technical". So when I'm looking at populating that field, I want it to pull back the area value "technical" for the current logged in user. Instead of getting that value it seems to only pull the relational ID. Any ideas? I hope hat helps explain it a bit better :-)